# Image breaks table in Outlook signature

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have an email signature designed and it works perfectly when viewed in a browser.

This is my code:

```html
<html>
 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
 
<body style="padding:0;margin:0">
 
<table border="0" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 20px 0px 6px 12px;" valign="top"><span style="text-align: left; color: #434343; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 21px;"><strong style="color: #000;">Alex Anderson</strong> - Founder and CEO</span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #444444;">
<td style="padding: 7px 0px 3px 12px;" valign="top"><a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: .4px;" href="tel:0412 533 227"> <span style="width: 15px; float: left;">M </span>: 0412 533 227</a></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #444444;">
<td style="padding: 0px 0px 3px 12px;" valign="top"><a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: .4px;" href="mailto:alex@chessworkgroup.com.au"><span style="width: 15px; float: left;">E </span>: alex@chessworkgroup.com.au</a></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #444444;">
<td style="padding: 0px 0px 3px 12px;" valign="top"><a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: .4px;" href="https://chessworkgroup.com.au/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> <span style="width: 15px; float: left;"> W </span>: http://www.chessworkgroup.com.au</a></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #444444;">
<td style="padding: 0px 0px 6px 12px;" valign="top"><a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: .4px;" href="https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Chesswork+Group/@-31.9449216,115.8575528,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x6e71710817e5b662!8m2!3d-31.9449216!4d115.8575528" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> <span style="width: 15px; float: left;"> O </span>: 283 Newcastle Street, Northbridge, Perth WA 6003</a></td>
</tr>
<tr style="padding: 0px 0px; position: relative; width: 100%;">
<td style="position: absolute; top: -130px; left: auto; right: 5%;” valign="top"><img src="https://chessworkgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/pic.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #000000; display: table; width: 100%;">
<td valign="top"><a href="https://chessworkgroup.com.au/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> <img style="padding: 11.5px 0px 9px 0px;" src="https://chessworkgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/logo_email.jpg" alt="" /> </a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
 
</body>
 
<style>
a {color: #F77A1E;}
</style>
 
</html>
```

However as soon as I place this into Outlook 2016 and try to use it as a signature it places the circle image between the address and logo (see attachment).

I have tried floating the image to the right with no success and wonder if this is even possible.

Comment: I am unable to see attachment, could you update link.

Comment: What is the result you are looking for can you attach an image, by the way, the `position` attribute will mess your signature. so don't use it and dost style `<tr>` it's not supported on some `email client`

Comment: OK so the result I would like is for the signature to look like this in Outlook:

https://chessworkgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/correct.jpg

However this is what happens with my code:

https://chessworkgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/wrong.jpg

Comment: Hi halfer, unfortunately this still displays incorrectly in Outlook, see here http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=09403727316899499783&t=0940372731689949978388962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been informed by numerous people that this is not possible in Outlook.

Therefore I am closing the question.

Thank you for all that tried to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check now issue is resolved.

```html
<html>
 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
 
<body style="padding:0;margin:0">
 
<table border="0" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr style="padding: 0px 0px; position: relative; width: 100%;">
<td style="position: absolute; top: -130px; left: auto; ” valign="top"><img src="https://chessworkgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/pic.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 20px 0px 6px 12px;" valign="top"><span style="text-align: left; color: #434343; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 21px;"><strong style="color: #000;">Alex Anderson</strong> - Founder and CEO</span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #444444;">
<td style="padding: 7px 0px 3px 12px;" valign="top"><a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: .4px;" href="tel:0412 533 227"> <span style="width: 15px; float: left;">M </span>: 0412 533 227</a></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #444444;">
<td style="padding: 0px 0px 3px 12px;" valign="top"><a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: .4px;" href="mailto:alex@chessworkgroup.com.au"><span style="width: 15px; float: left;">E </span>: alex@chessworkgroup.com.au</a></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #444444;">
<td style="padding: 0px 0px 3px 12px;" valign="top"><a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: .4px;" href="https://chessworkgroup.com.au/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> <span style="width: 15px; float: left;"> W </span>: http://www.chessworkgroup.com.au</a></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #444444;">
<td style="padding: 0px 0px 6px 12px;" valign="top"><a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: .4px;" href="https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Chesswork+Group/@-31.9449216,115.8575528,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x6e71710817e5b662!8m2!3d-31.9449216!4d115.8575528" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> <span style="width: 15px; float: left;"> O </span>: 283 Newcastle Street, Northbridge, Perth WA 6003</a></td>
</tr>

<tr style="background-color: #000000; display: table; width: 100%;">
<td valign="top"><a href="https://chessworkgroup.com.au/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> <img style="padding: 11.5px 0px 9px 0px;" src="https://chessworkgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/logo_email.jpg" alt="" /> </a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
 
</body>
 
<style>
a {color: #F77A1E;}
</style>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, unfortunately in Outlook the signature displays like this:

https://chessworkgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Capture.jpg

Comment: can you share the image how you want to display your signature. so i can provide you exact same output

Comment: OK so the result I would like is for the signature to look like this in Outlook:

chessworkgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/correct.jpg

However this is what happens with my code:

chessworkgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/wrong.jpg